# Using SUBSTR to remove first few and last few characters, then compare table column values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am looking for help on finding inconsistencies between two columns from two different tables.

Table1 has ColumnA

Table2 has ColumnB

ColumnA and ColumnB have values that need to be removed first before comparing them, for example

```
ColumnA = TZ-ZA112
ColumnA = TZ-RT322
ColumnA = TZ-JKAAA
ColumnB = TZ-ZA112,-2
ColumnB = TZ-HHASS,-4
ColumnB = TZ-RT322,4-
```

So essentially, I need to have TZ- (first three) and ,## (last three) removed before comparing, then I need to have the query spit out the values that do not exist in either column. So what the output should be is

```
HHASS
JKAAA
```

I will be honest, I can't wrap my ahead around using the SUBSTR and INSTR together, while combining these tables to produce this output.

Comment: Will the first three characters will always be `TZ-`?

Comment: @Nivas No they wont be, this is just an example.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you will always need to start from the 4th character in columnA and column B, and need to fetch the `substr` until the `,` character the code below would work.

To get the values not in columnA and in columnB, use `minus`. This has to be repeated for values not in columnB and in columnA. Finally, do a `union` to get the desired result.

```
(select substr(columnA, 4, instr(columnA,',')-1) col from table1
minus
select substr(columnB, 4, instr(columnB,',')-1) col from table2
)
union all
(select substr(columnB, 4, instr(columnB,',')-1) col from table2
minus
select substr(columnA, 4, instr(columnA,',')-1) col from table1
)
```

Comment: Do you mind also explaining how you are using substr and instr in this? Thank you!

Comment: What if there are multiple commas in one of the values in the columns?

Comment: you will get the occurrence of the first `,` in the answer above. If you have to handle multiple `,` , the query would get complex. if you show some sample data it would be easier to explain

Comment: I just need the last two values of the data on the column trimmed, that will be consistent throughout the query, and it will only need to be trimmed on columnB not columnA

Comment: did you try the query in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

According to this site: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_convert_set_to_join_sql_parameter.htm, replacing the MINUS operator with a NOT IN subquery is faster.  I would be interested to see proof of this.  Anyway I went with it using REGEXP_REPLACE since I am allergic to nested INSTR/SUBSTR calls.

First I used WITH clauses to set up data Table1 and Table2 to act as the original data tables (of course you already have these so this part would not be needed).  Note I added an additional row with an embedded comma in there to satisfy a question in the comments from the OP.  Then, still using WITH clauses I made T1_converted and T2_converted from the same data but with the leading 3 characters stripped from Table1/ColumnA and the leading 3 and trailing 3 stripped from Table2/ColumnB.  Doing this reduces the number of REGEXP_REPLACE calls that would be needed in the actual select at the bottom and prepares the data to make the select easier to follow. Note - The assumption is there will always be 3 leading characters to strip in both tables and 3 trailing characters to strip in table2.  If this should change, the regex's will have to change.

```
SQL> -- Simulates original table
SQL> with Table1(ColumnA) as (
  2    select 'TZ-ZA112' from dual
  3    union
  4    select 'TZ-RT322' from dual
  5    union
  6    select 'TZ-JKAAA' from dual
  7  ),
  8  -- Simulates original table
  9       Table2(ColumnB) as (
 10    select 'TZ-ZA112,-2' from dual
 11    union
 12    select 'TZ-HHASS,-4' from dual
 13    union
 14    select 'TZ-RT322,4-' from dual
 15    union
 16    select 'TZ-R,T322,4-' from dual  -- make sure commas are handled
 17  ),
 18  -- Strip leading 3 characters from table 1
 19       T1_converted(ColA) as (
 20    select regexp_replace(ColumnA, '^.{3}(.*)$', '\1') from Table1
 21  ),
 22  -- Strip leading and trailing 3 characters from table 2
 23       T2_converted(ColB) as (
 24    select regexp_replace(ColumnB, '^.{3}(.*).{3}$', '\1') from Table2
 25  )
 26  -- Get the differences
 27  select ColA Unique
 28  from T1_converted
 29  where (ColA) not in
 30     (select ColB from T2_converted)
 31     union all
 32  select ColB from T2_converted
 33  where (ColB) not in
 34     (select ColA from T1_converted);
```

The output:

```
Unique
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
JKAAA
R,T322
HHASS

SQL>
```

I don't see the value in this without including the table name that has the data (or is missing the data?), but that isn't in your requirements so I'll leave that to you as an exercise to suss out